# Using char array as number for math in C++

Tags: c++, math, operators, int, arrays

I'm trying to make 128 and 256 bit integers in C++, and noticed casting `char**` to `int*` and `int*` to `int` (and backwards) can be used to convert char arrays to integers and integers to char arrays.
Also, `char* + int` works fine.

However, when I try `char* + char*` the compiler tells me the types are invalid. Is there any workaround for this, or will I have to write my own functions for the operators?

For example:

```
int32_t intValue = 2147483647;
char *charPointer = *( char** ) &intValue;
charPointer += 2147483647;
charPointer += 2;
cout << ( *( int64_t* ) &charPointer )  << endl;
```

output: 4294967296

Basically, what I do should be something like the following:

```
int32_t intValue = 2147483647;
```

somewhere in memory:

```
[ 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C ] ( address, in hex )
[ .. .. FF FF FF 7F .. .. ] ( value, in hex )
```

then:

```
char *charPointer = *( char** ) &intValue;
```

somewhere in memory:

```
[ 58 59 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F ] ( address, in hex )
[ .. .. 07 00 00 00 .. .. ] ( value, in hex )
```

then:

```
charPointer += 2147483647;
```

I honestly have no idea what happens here.
It seems like it does something like this though:

```
[ 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C ] ( address, in hex )
[ .. .. FF FF FF FE .. .. ] ( value, in hex )
```

then:

```
charPointer += 2;
```

Same here.
Something like this:

```
[ 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C ] ( address, in hex )
[ .. .. 00 00 00 00 01 .. ] ( value, in hex )
```

And at last I just print it *as if* it were an 8 byte integer:

```
cout << ( *( int64_t* ) &charPointer )  << endl;
```

So, can anybody explain why it isn't the value of the pointer that is added but the value of what's being pointed to?

Comment: Please give some code demonstrating what you mean.  Why would you want to add a pointer to another pointer?

Comment: I don't think `char* + int` (or `int*` to `int` (or backwards)) does what you think it does

Comment: the premises of the question are invalid. but google "bigint c++"

Comment: @RPFeltz: Based on how you responded to my answer, I can see this isn't going to be construcive. So I've deleted it. The `+= 10000` example I gave was a bad one. But try `int intValue = 2147483647;` and `charValue += 2147483647; charValue += 2;` and you'll see...

Comment: Based on how you responded to us as well as your edits, I honestly can't tell if you really don't understand what's going on, or if you're just trolling. (I hope it's the former though.) So I won't keep playing this counter-example game. But consider what will happen when the "actual" number overflows 64-bits. Or if you just compile for 32-bit...

Comment: Oh, screw this, I'm confused. I'll check back later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These conversions exist, but they don't do what you think they do. Converting a pointer to an integer is just treating it as an integer; it's not doing any actual "math". For example, `char * s = "abcd"; int i = (int) s;` will not give the same result every time, because `s` and `i` are both just the memory address that the string starts at. Neither has anything to do with the actual contents of the string.

Similarly, `char* + int` is just taking an offset. To write `char * s = "abcd"; char * t = s + 2;` is just another way to write `char * s = "abcd"; char * t = &(s[2]);`; that is, `s` is the memory location of the `'a'`, and `t` is the memory location of the `'c'` (`s`, offset by two `char`-widths, that is, two bytes). No actual math has taken place, except in the sense that "pointer arithmetic" requires math to compute byte offsets and find memory locations.

`char * + char *` doesn't make sense: what would it mean to "add" two memory locations together?

**Edit:** Here is the code you added to your question:

```
int intValue = 5198;
char *charValue = *( char** ) &intValue;
charValue += 100;
cout << ( *( int* ) &charValue )  << endl;
```

Let me expand it a bit, so it's a bit clearer what's going on:

```
int intValue = 5198;
int * intPtr = &intValue;
// intPtr is now the address of the memory location containing intValue
char ** charPtrPtr = (char**) intPtr;
// charPtrPtr is now the address of the memory location containing intValue,
// but *pretending* that it's the address of a memory location that in turn
// contains the address of a memory location containing a char.
char *charPtr = *charPtrPtr;
// charPtr (note: you called it "charValue", but I've renamed it for clarity)
// is now intValue, but *pretending* that it's the address of a memory
// location containing a char.
charPtr += 100;
// charPtr is now 100 more than it was. It's still really just an integer,
// pretending to be a memory location. The above statement is equivalent to
// "charPtr = &(charPtr[100]);", that is, it sets charPtr to point 100 bytes
// later than it did before, but since it's not actually pointing to a real
// memory location, that's a poor way to look at it.
char ** charPtrPtr2 = &charPtr;
// charPtrPtr2 is now the address of the memory location containing charPtr.
// Note that it is *not* the same as charPtrPtr; we used charPtrPtr to
// initialize charPtr, but the two memory locations are distinct.
int * intPtr2 = (int *) charPtrPtr2;
// intPtr2 is now the address of the memory location containing charPtr, but
// *pretending* that it's the address of a memory location containing an
// integer.
int intValue2 = *intPtr2;
// intValue2 is now the integer that results from reading out of charPtrPtr2
// as though it were actually pointing to an integer. Which, in a perverse
// way, is actually true: charPtrPtr2 pointed to a memory location that held
// a value that was never *really* a memory location, anyway, just an integer
// masquerading as one. But this will depend on the specific platform,
// because there's no guarantee that an "int" and a pointer are the same
// size -- on some platforms "int" is 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits.
cout << intValue2  << endl;
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I edited the question.

Comment: @RPFeltz: Sorry, but I *did* understand. I've edited my answer to reflect your edits.

Comment: I do not understand why people do not upvote your answer. +1

Comment: It does not make any sense for it to work anyway. Also, I only wish to use it as a container, I'll make something to convert it to decimal later, so the size of int shouldn't matter. I'll edit it again, with huge numbers and more specific types.

Comment: @RPFeltz: I think it's pretty reasonable to store your big-int data in a `char[]`, and naturally you'll have lots of `char*`s and potentially even `char**`s as part of that, and you'll have to do conversions between `char` and `int` and potentially even `char*` and `int*` (though the latter will be complicated by endianness considerations; `*(int*)"\0\0\0\xFF"` will be 255 on some systems, 4278190080 on some systems, and so on). That's all well and good. But it does *not* make sense to convert between `char*` and `int`, or between `char**` and `int*`. You will gain *nothing* from storing

Comment: pointers as `int`s, and you will *certainly* gain nothing from storing arbitrary integers as `char*`s. `char * s = 300;` is a bug. It's possible to write a working program that contains it, but the program will work in *spite* of this bad decision, not *because* of it.

Comment: @RPFeltz: Also, you really don't need to notify me when you edit your question to address one of Mysticial's points, since I am not making the same points. (I'm not saying that his/her points are wrong, or that they're right; only that they have nothing to do with my answer.)